# AngularJS: Register Controller from separate .js file

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, ng-controller

I am new to AngularJS and using plnkr.co to learn how to use angular. I have having some difficulty registering a Controller this is stored in a separate .js from where the module is initialized. Can anybody tell me why the below does not work?

index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.6"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script scr="mainCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js File

```js
angular.module('plunker', []);
```

mainCtrl.js File

```js
angular.module('plunker')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'GitHub';
  }]);
```

For me, this produces an Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

Comment: Following is link to the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=catalogue

Comment: pretty easy to inspect in network tab of dev tools to see file isn't being loaded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
<script scr="mainCtrl.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="mainCtrl.js"></script>
```

Because of the typo (`scr` instead of `src`), the source file holding `MainCtrl` is not loaded, therefore `MainCtrl` is undefined.

Comment: Do you have any link from the help center about that?

Comment: I am too dependent on intellisense these days :)

Comment: It's one of the reasons listed under "close" voting button, but think of it like this - would the answer be of much help to a future visitor? I don't think so, since the solution is barely related to the purported issue of the original question, and the OP can be helped via comment.